# Unable to update the purchase price on vendor Sublist in Netsuite when record is modified via CSV import

Tags: netsuite

[image: Vendor Sublist on item record]

Unable to set the purchase prices on the vendor sublist when a record is updated via CSV import the value is available before the record is saved.
I have used the following code.

```
     if(lineNumber != -1){
                                itemRec.selectLine({sublistId: 'itemvendor', line: lineNumber});
                                var hasSubrecord = itemRec.hasCurrentSublistSubrecord({sublistId: 'itemvendor',fieldId: 'itemvendorprice'});
                                if(hasSubrecord == true || hasSubrecord == 'T' || hasSubrecord == 'true'){
                                    var sublistRecord                     =                 itemRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({ sublistId: 'itemvendor',fieldId: 'itemvendorprice'});
                                    var count                             =                 sublistRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines'}); 
                                    if(count>0){
                                        log.debug("enetered in if ")
                                        sublistRecord.selectLine({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines',line:0});
                                            var Currency                      =               vendorResults[i].getValue({name: "currency", label: "Currency"});
                                        log.debug("Currency",Currency);
                                        sublistRecord.selectNewLine({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines'});
                                        sublistRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines', fieldId: 'vendorcurrency',value: prmCurrency});
                                        if(createModePrice)
                                            sublistRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines', fieldId: 'vendorprice',value: createModePrice,ignoreFieldChange: true});
                                        if(createModePrice){
                                            log.debug("Price in if",createModePrice);
                                            sublistRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines', fieldId: 'vendorprice',value: createModePrice,ignoreFieldChange: true});
                                        }

                                        sublistRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines'});
                                        sublistRecord.selectLine({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines',line:0});
                                        var price = sublistRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines', fieldId: 'vendorprice'});
                                        sublistRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'itemvendorpricelines'});
                                        log.debug("price before commiting",price);

                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: I see that you are setting 'vendorprice' which I believe (I'm not sure) is not the purchase price. There was the field purchaseprice, IIRC